# SSRS Matrix columns show currrent month

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm stuck with a problem in SSRS 2012 that maybe is very simple:

I have a matrix with a *group row* (employee) and a *group column* (last 12 months); the values are *COUNT(practicesDone)* - i.e. the amount of practices worked.
I want the matrix to show an extra column on the right (after all the columns of the months, and clearly outside the column group) with again the number of practices for the current month.

Is it possible to achieve that?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, it's pretty simple.
I have assumed that your dataset contains a column that has a date for each entry and that the data returned only covers 12 months so the same month would not appear for different years. If your data does have multiple years, look at the second expression below.

Right-click your month column and then to "Insert Column --> Outside Group - Right"

Now set the expression for the text box to

```
=COUNT(IIF(MONTH(Fields!myDateColumn.Value) = MONTH(TODAY()), 1, Nothing))
```

You could swap COUNT for SUM and it should do the same thing but either will work.
All we are doing here is comparing the all data in scope which, due to the placement of the text box means the scope is the entire rowgroup. Then for all that data, check if the month matches the current month, if it does set it to 1 is not set it to `nothing` then count/sum all results. `Count` conveniently ignores 'nothing'.

If you data covers more than 12 months then you can still do this but you'll have to add a bit more to handle years and months like this.

```
=COUNT(
      IIF(
          MONTH(Fields!myDateColumn.Value) = MONTH(TODAY())
          AND YEAR(Fields!myDateColumn.Value) = YEAR(TODAY()), 
          1, 
          Nothing
         )
      )
```